# How to serialize a collection of derived data-sets

Tags: c#, serialization, collections, dataset

I'm new to serialization, so most likely I am missing something obvious!

I have a class called ResultsCollection that is a four-dimension data structure -- a collection of objects that are derived from the DataSet class.  Each modified DataSet holds a collection of objects derived from DataTable.  The relevant bits of code are:

```
[Serializable]
public class ResultsCollection : CollectionBase, ISerializable
{
  // indexer
  public MyDataSet this[int index] { get { return (MyDataSet)List[index]; } }
}
[Serializable]
public class MyDataSet : DataSet, ISerializable
{
  // member variable that *overrides* the Tables property of the standard DataSet class
  public new TablesCollection Tables;
}
[Serializable]
public class TablesCollection : CollectionBase, ISerializable
{
  // indexer
  public MyDataTable this[int index] { get { return (MyDataTable)List[index]; } }
}
[Serializable]
public class MyDataTable : DataTable, ISerializable
{
  ...
}
```

I have implemented the ISerializable interface by including a public Serialization constructor and a public GetObjectData function, as shown here:

```
// ResultsCollection -- serialize all variables and also the inner list itself
public ResultsCollection(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt) : base()
{
  _memberVariable = (bool)info.GetValue("_memberVariable", typeof(bool));
  ArrayList innerList = (ArrayList)info.GetValue("List", typeof(ArrayList));
  InnerList.AddRange(innerList);
}
public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
{
  info.AddValue("_memberVariable", _memberVariable);
  info.AddValue("List", InnerList);
}

// MyDataSet -- call standard base-class (DataSet) serialization functions in addition to serializing members
public MyDataSet(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt) : base(info, ctxt)
{
  _memberVariable = (bool)info.GetValue("_memberVariable", typeof(bool));
  Tables = (TablesCollection)info.GetValue("Tables", typeof(TablesCollection));
}
public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
{
  base.GetObjectData(info, ctxt);
  info.AddValue("_memberVariable", _memberVariable);
  info.AddValue("Tables", Tables);
}

// TablesCollection -- serialize all variables and also the inner list itself
public TablesCollection(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt) : base()
{
  _memberVariable = (bool)info.GetValue("_memberVariable", typeof(bool));
  ArrayList innerList = (ArrayList)info.GetValue("List", typeof(ArrayList));
  InnerList.AddRange(innerList);
}
public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
{
  info.AddValue("_memberVariable", _memberVariable);
  info.AddValue("List", InnerList);
}

// MyDataTable -- call standard base-class (DataTable) serialization functions in addition to serializing members
public MyDataSet(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt) : base(info, ctxt)
{
  _memberVariable = (bool)info.GetValue("_memberVariable", typeof(bool));
}
public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
{
  base.GetObjectData(info, ctxt);
  info.AddValue("_memberVariable", _memberVariable);
}
```

I have a single ResultsCollection object that I want to store in ViewState, in order to retrieve it on the next post-back (hence all this trouble).  For the initial request, things appear to be working: I have set break-points in the Serialization functions and the data members are indeed being serialized.  However, upon deserialization, the member variables are loaded properly but the List objects are full of null members.  My code crashes out when I try to retrieve the DataSetName property from the first MyDataSet object in the ResultsCollection.

Comment: If you are new to serialization, you might want to look into http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/. I found it easier to use than the [Serialization] attributes.

Comment: I think it is much easier to use `[Serializable]` only. You must make sure that every class have a relation with the serialized class is marked `[Serializable]` too.

Comment: Personally, I prefer XML Serialization to binary.  I find it significantly easier to use, and being able to look at the raw data afterwards lets you know if something is wrong with it.  That being said, I acknowledge that there are times when its the wrong way to go.  I still prefer though =D

Comment: @LKIM -- thanks for the suggestion.  If I can't find a solution in "conventional code" I'll give it a try!

Comment: @Desolator -- I tried that, but it didn't work either.  I forget what the error was but I can find out if that would be useful.

Comment: @Nevyn -- in this case, I want to dump the thing in ViewState, so I thought that binary would be smaller and faster: is this wrong?

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664267/serializing-an-arraylist-in-c-sharp

Comment: @LKIM -- it might if I were using XmlSerialization but I was trying to use binary.  Is it not possible to serialize collection objects in binary?  (That could be where I'm going wrong!)

Comment: you are correct, binary is the more compact serialized form.  Have you debugged through the de-serialize operations like you have the serialize ones, to see what its getting both in raw and in value for the data members?

Comment: @Nevyn -- yes indeed; that's how I know that the collection items are present but NULL.  They're not null when they're going in, I promise ... could I be missing some more [Serializable] attributes somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that **CollectionBase and ISerializable are incompatible**, possibly because the InnerList property of CollectionBase is read-only.  Therefore what I needed to do was to *remove* the ISerializable definitions from the two CollectionBase-derived classes, i.e.:

```
[Serializable]
public class ResultsCollection : CollectionBase
{
  // indexer
  public MyDataSet this[int index] { get { return (MyDataSet)List[index]; } }
}
[Serializable]
public class MyDataSet : DataSet, ISerializable
{
  // member variable that *overrides* the Tables property of the standard DataSet class
  public new TablesCollection Tables;
}
[Serializable]
public class TablesCollection : CollectionBase
{
  // indexer
  public MyDataTable this[int index] { get { return (MyDataTable)List[index]; } }
}
[Serializable]
public class MyDataTable : DataTable, ISerializable
{
  ...
}
```